# Export all IAM users, roles and policies from AWS organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm looking for a simple way to export all IAM users, roles and policies from an AWS organization account. This should include IAM resources from member accounts in the export.

All the APIs I found like `GetAccountAuthorizationDetails` are account specific.

How would I achieve this, without fetching all accounts and iterating through them ?

Comment: Where you say member accounts, you mean orgs you have access keys for?

Comment: Ignore that comment, just reread your question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [list accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/list-accounts.html) and then use the right access keys to get each set of users,roles and policies I believe.

So although you said fetch all without iterating them, that's not possible, you can't just fetch everything, that'd be insanity for number security purposes.

Update (19/4/2021): Netflix just released [ConsoleMe](https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/04/netflix-consoleme-aws/) looks good for your use case.

Comment: So there is no aws tool to create an "iam report" for a whole aws organization?

Comment: I don't believe so buddy, not at the detail you want, I'm just checking give me 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't find and needed to create a simple one.

https://github.com/umihico/iam-user-permissions-viwer